# Feeds import programatically

Tags: commerce, feeds

im using feeds commerce on eshop. Im trying to import large feed with this code:

```
 $myFeed = feeds_source('my_feed'); while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $myFeed->import());
```

But after run im getting this message:

> FeedsLockException: Cannot acquire lock for source my_feed / 0. in
>   FeedsSource->acquireLock() (line 791 of
>   sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsSource.inc).

Im calling script via url every 10 minutes with server cron and still getting error.

Can someone help me and explain what im doing wrong?